Fetching data from an API that has null values
So when I tried to get the JsonObject from the array, I get an error that says it should start on line 1:

`ERROR 34879 --- [gbac] [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]] with root cause
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
`

But when I switch it up to the JSONArray to return a JSON object it returns an empty array when I test it.
\[\]

Here's the JSON API Format:
[
  {
    "id": "298f43b988d512301f1283f58465be55",
    "sport_key": "basketball_nba",
    "sport_title": "NBA",
    "commence_time": "2024-04-16T23:40:00Z",
    "completed": false,
    "home_team": "New Orleans Pelicans",
    "away_team": "Los Angeles Lakers",
    "scores": null,
    "last_update": null
  },
  {
    "id": "c0b61bf137d5bf5aafe6ade79b6800a1",
    "sport_key": "basketball_nba",
    "sport_title": "NBA",
    "commence_time": "2024-04-17T02:00:00Z",
    "completed": false,
    "home_team": "Sacramento Kings",
    "away_team": "Golden State Warriors",
    "scores": null,
    "last_update": null
  },
  {
    "id": "f13eb486120d8466fc3d004f69280112",
    "sport_key": "basketball_nba",
    "sport_title": "NBA",
    "commence_time": "2024-04-17T23:10:00Z",
    "completed": false,
    "home_team": "Philadelphia 76ers",
    "away_team": "Miami Heat",
    "scores": null,
    "last_update": null
  }
]

Here's the code to parse the scores from the API into JSONobject or JSONArray:
public List<Score> parseScore(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String sportId = jsonObject.getString("id");
                // Check if scores is null or not
                if (!jsonObject.isNull("scores")) {
                    JSONArray scoreArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("scores");
                    for (int j = 0; j < scoreArray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject scoreObj = scoreArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        String scoreValue = scoreObj.optString("score", "n/a");
                        String name = scoreObj.optString("name", "n/a");
                        if (scoreValue != null && name != null) {
                            Score scoreModel = new Score();
                            scoreModel.setSport_Id(sportId);
                            scoreModel.setScore(scoreValue);
                            scoreModel.setName(name);
                            scores.add(scoreModel);
                        } else {
                            // Log a warning or handle the missing data appropriately
                            System.out.println("Invalid or missing score data in JSON object.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // Log or handle JSON parsing error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return scores;
    }

The getNBAScores method:
@GetMapping("/scores/nba")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Score>> getNBAScores() {
        // Parse the mocked response
        List<Score> nbaScores = oddsAPIAdapter.parseScore(new JSONArray(oddsAPIAdapter.mockedScoreResponse));

        // Save scores to the database (assuming sportRepository.save(score) is correctly implemented)

        // Return the NBA scores
        return new ResponseEntity<>(nbaScores, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

I'm new to APIs and developing with springboot/postman I appreciate the feedback or constructive criticism thrown my way.
I was expecting it to be able to get the scores of each individual NBA game even if the game hasn't taken place yet. Also, this API call is old, I'm just using it to save on my free API keys.
This project could be much better but I am on a time crunch.
